# SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: sql, localdb

I'm looking for a better alternative to MS Access MDb files. MS SQLServer 2012 LocalDB looks like the perfect solution. I've done some testing and it seems to do the trick.

What I need to find out is

1. How secure is LocalDB ?
2. Can it be made any more secure ?

I have an application that field workers use and would like to to be able to send them updated data files from time to time (if there are significant schema changes and or associated data) but would like the data contained to be managed by a password (and maybe username). The application (Winforms or WPF) would manage the password.

Currently I use a MS Access mdb file with database password. Its a good solution for basic security. But the performance of it isn't that good for what the app does, plus it wouldn't take a brain surgeon to crack the password and get access to the database.

Testing LocalDB gives the performance that I need but I'm just wondering if its possible to increase the security. So if someone managed to get a hold of the data file they would have a hard time accessing the data.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks all

Comment: I beleive there will be more security. If u need it more go for encryption at frontend..!

Comment: SQL Server LocalDB does not support data encryption.